# How to access elements attributes from custom directive while keeping access to parent scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

Essentially I want to be able to access the parent scope of the directive I have created, but I also want to be able to access the attributes that I have placed onto the element.

For example relevant js

```
app.directive('testDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict:"E",
        templateUrl:"directive.html",
        scope:{
            testAttribute: '='
        }
    };
});

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
     $scope.name = 'henry'
}
```

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <test-directive test-attribute="Hello"></test-directive>
</div>
```

directive.html

```
{{testAttribute}}
{{name}}
```

Output is "Hello" instead of "Hello Henry"

So just to clarrify, All I want to be able to do is access the attributes and the parent scope.

Comment: In your directive.html, you can use `{{$parent.name}}` instead to access the property `name`. But it is not proper since it does not promote reusability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you are trying to do, do not need a two way binding. You are trying to access the text assigned as attribute. You could just write your directive as:-

```
.directive('testDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict:"E",
        //scope:true,   //apply if required
        templateUrl:"directive.html",
        link:function(scope, elm, attrs){
           scope.testAttribute = attrs.testAttribute; //Get it from attributes
        }
    };
});
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/xKiBfO?p=preview)**

Now here scope property of directive settings is going to use the parent scope itself. But ideal scenarios you may want to use `scope:true` (Child scope of parent) or a `2 way binding` wit isolated scope. But at this point, since not really sure what is your original goal, this is a solution based on what you have in your question.

So to summarize:-

> I want to be able to access the parent scope of the directive I have created

Remove the isolated scope and just use parent's scope.

> but I also want to be able to access the attributes that I have placed onto the element.

Use `attrs` argument of the link function (`attrs.testAttribute`). If you want to evaluate it as a bound value the do (`scope.$eval(attrs.testAttribute)`)

Comment: Hey thanks for the thorough explanation, it works well, however when you have more than one directive it seems to take the last directive's attribute and apply it to all of the directives. [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/XPilCbNtBJ5HgvSUrLe3?p=preview)

Comment: Like this.. http://plnkr.co/edit/IGc3tK?p=preview. last line in my answer. You coul also use a 2 way binding(if required).